# HTML and JS on Windows only - input field does not generate onkeup/down events for non-english chars

Tags: javascript, html, key-events, non-english

I have a very simple code with a text input box and a simple onkeyup handler. For some reason if my keyboard is in non-English language ( Russian, for example ) - they chars will be shown in the input field but no events will be generated. Pressing speace,enter or even arrows will generate the event and then the whole text is visible to the code.

This behavior is only like that on Windows ( IE, chrome, Edge ). On MAC it works as expected ( Chrome, Safari )

```js
function line_Change(obj)
{
   alert("here");
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="input1" onkeyup = "line_Change(this)" placeholder="Try typing something in here!">
  <label for="input1">Line 1</label>
```

EDIT: I found out that it does not work when connected to Windows from macOS thru TeamViewer. When working directly on Windows - the results are as expected

Comment: would an `onchange="lineChange(this)"` work here? did see there were some differences in handling of the change events with a `<select>` vs an `<input>` but if you're working with inputs should work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Windows 8.1, I tried Arabic and Russian and it's working http://jsfiddle.net/59kr8374/2/

Comment: I found the issue ! I did not think it was important to mention but till now I did not actually try it directly on Windows machines - I remotely connected (TeamViewer) to them... After seeing comments that it works ok ( thank you @Dan and @lkroneman) I actually reached to the real machines and it works !